# If $AB=BA=0$ and $A+B$ is invertible, is $A-B$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB=BA=0$ and $A+B$ is invertible. Is it true that $A-B$ is also invertible?

Comment: Please refrain from using ALL CAPS. Also please avoid abbreviations like "s.t."

Comment: The all caps thing and lack of description of what you have tried, please look at what was done with your other question. This is not acceptable behavior on math.SE.

Answer (score 10):

Note that $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2=A^2+B^2$ is invertible.

Similarly, we see $(A-B)^2=A^2+B^2$. The square of a non-invertible matrix cannot be invertible, so $A-B$ must be invertible.